# yahoo boss: limit of search

Tags: yahoo-boss-api

I use Yahoo BOSS for data crawling.
When I use yahoo.fr and search for "restaurant" keyword, it shows results: 160 millions

But after going to page 9 result, there is no more 160 millions results, but only 860 results remaining

Try by yourself: go to yahoo.fr and type in 'restaurant' keyword
Page1 : 160 Millions results
Page2 : 160 millions results
then... 860 results !

How can I go futher ?

Despite Yahoo claims 160 millions of results, you can only access to first 900 ones

Comment: This question is totally unclear.

Comment: Sorry for my english: I edited the question. But this is VERY simple to understand: Despite Yahoo claims 160milloins of results, you can only access to first 900 ones !

Comment: Still unclear. The ambiguity is not because of English. The question can be interpreted in two ways: (1) Yahoo returns 160 million as the number of results, and it denies permission after 860 results. So how do I get these permission? (2) Yahoo returns 160 million as the number of results, but the actual result count is much less. Can I get a more accurate count?  So out of these which one is your question? Or is it something else?

Comment: And either way, you can get the answers in the Yahoo API doc. Hopefully.

Comment: Infact it looks that Yahoo BOSS has a limit: it just retrives the top 1000 results.